# How to upload images to Amazon S3 services in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a mobile app on Android Platform where uploading of images to the bucket is one heck of an issue.
I followed the transfer utility tutorial but it didn't got to be working.

Find my android file screenshot below.

[utility setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm1zP.png)

The Utils class contains the necessary credentials which i counter checked no. of times.

Please help me out, stuck with it for about a week now and yet no result.

Comment: Hey, why dont you download complete automated source code from amazon mobile hub. You need to enable the cloud logic data. they will add everything. just do it.

Comment: atleast don't give negative points to the question, you can say politely..

Comment: sorry, sree reddy. Also i want to tell you that i set up aws-mobile hub but yet it is not uploading images

Comment: Go to MobileHub -> open your app - > click on UserData Storage -> click on  Store User Data  . Below you can find " Build your app " click on it.  select android  - > You can see "download the android source package" click anda zip file wil be download. open in android studio. . they will give complete automated source code. just run the app. you will see. I have tired. and Its working for me. they have some utility classes for file upload. please try this.

Comment: thank you very much, got working

Comment: Should i write as answer ? if my steps are working  for you? let me know

Comment: as you wish @SreeReddyMenon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Giving an automated source code based on services that you have selected on [Amazon Mobile Hub](https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/)

Go to MobileHub -> open your app - > click on UserData Storage -> 
click on Store User Data . Below you can find " **Build your app** " 
click on it. select android - > You can see "download the android source package" click anda zip file wil be download. open in android studio. .

they will give complete automated source code. just run the app. you will see.
 I have tired. and Its working for me. they have some utility classes for file upload. please try this

[image]

[image]